# Improve Performance of Yahoo Finance Info on each stock

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

Im getting the list of all S&P 500 stocks and then storing each stocks info which contains a lot of financial information about 170 columns per stock in a dataframe the code is very slow and I was wondering if it could be improved.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import json
import datapackage
data_url = 'https://datahub.io/core/s-and-p-500-companies/datapackage.json'

# to load Data Package into storage
package = datapackage.Package(data_url)

# to load only tabular data
resources = package.resources
for resource in resources:
    if resource.tabular:
        data = pd.read_csv(resource.descriptor['path'])

spSymbols=data['Symbol']
sp500 =""
for i in spSymbols:
    sp500= sp500 + i +" " 
tickers= yf.Tickers(sp500)
dfStockInfo =[]
metricList=[]
#bottle neck ****
for i in spSymbols:
    stock = tickers.tickers.get(i)
    stockInfo= stock.info     
    metricList.append(stockInfo)
```

I would like to optimize the `tickers.tickers.get(i)` by trying to batch the calls.
For each stock it is making an API call.
I thought this line `tickers= yf.Tickers(sp500)` would have got me all the stock info at one time but seems not.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot improve this because, for each ticker you are recieving 155 columns:

```
metricList = []

for t in small:
    metricList.append(pd.DataFrame([yf.Ticker(t).info]))
    

df = pd.concat(metricList)
```

which is (for the first five tickers):

```
          zip       sector  fullTimeEmployees  \
0  55144-1000  Industrials            95000.0   
0  53224-9508  Industrials            13700.0   
0  60064-6400   Healthcare           113000.0   
0  60064-6400   Healthcare            50000.0   
0       01923   Healthcare                NaN   

                                 longBusinessSummary           city  \
0  3M Company operates as a diversified technolog...     Saint Paul   
0  A. O. Smith Corporation manufactures and marke...      Milwaukee   
0  Abbott Laboratories, together with its subsidi...  North Chicago   
0  AbbVie Inc. discovers, develops, manufactures,...  North Chicago   
0  Abiomed, Inc. engages in the research, develop...        Danvers   

          phone state        country companyOfficers                  website  \
0  651 733 1110    MN  United States              []       https://www.3m.com   
0  414 359 4000    WI  United States              []  https://www.aosmith.com   
0  224 667 6100    IL  United States              []   https://www.abbott.com   
0  847 932 7900    IL  United States              []   https://www.abbvie.com   
0  978 646 1400    MA  United States              []  https://www.abiomed.com   

   maxAge               address1                        industry  \
0       1              3M Center                   Conglomerates   
0       1  11270 West Park Place  Specialty Industrial Machinery   
0       1   100 Abbott Park Road                 Medical Devices   
0       1  1 North Waukegan Road      Drug Manufacturers—General   
0       1   22 Cherry Hill Drive                 Medical Devices   

   ebitdaMargins  profitMargins  grossMargins operatingCashflow  \
0        0.26768        0.15838       0.46331        6776999936   
0        0.19407        0.13587       0.36394         553200000   
0        0.30320        0.17354       0.58074              None   
0        0.50160        0.21999       0.69647              None   
0        0.27568        0.13230       0.81763              None   

   revenueGrowth  operatingMargins       ebitda  targetLowPrice  \
0         -0.002           0.21351   9457999872             118   
0          0.271           0.17307    727299968              52   
0          0.138           0.22483  13496500224             115   
0          0.041           0.35288  28453249024             115   
0          0.119           0.24881    284437984             275   

  recommendationKey  grossProfits freeCashflow  targetMedianPrice  \
0              hold   16579000000   4292875008              157.0   
0              hold    1310900000    351275008               75.0   
0               buy   25009000000         None              141.0   
0               buy   38883000000         None              167.5   
0               buy     843595000         None              357.5   

   currentPrice  earningsGrowth currentRatio returnOnAssets  \
0        128.49          -0.184        1.579        0.10136   
0         57.19           0.261        1.718        0.12393   
0        110.22           0.370         None           None   
0        153.80           0.261         None           None   
0        256.66           0.049        7.053         0.1013   

   numberOfAnalystOpinions  targetMeanPrice  debtToEquity returnOnEquity  \
0                       19           158.36       117.329         0.3888   
0                        9            72.67        17.690        0.27841   
0                       20           141.77        53.439           None   
0                       23           164.73       502.701           None   
0                        6           354.17         0.894        0.09637   

   targetHighPrice    totalCash    totalDebt  totalRevenue  totalCashPerShare  \
0            210.0   3359000064  17603999744   35333001216              5.903   
0             85.0    579400000    320000000    3747599872              3.660   
0            158.5  10248999936  19250999296   44514000896              5.812   
0            200.0   9829999616  77596999680   56725000192              5.558   
0            425.0    758606976     13439000    1031753024             16.656   

  financialCurrency  revenuePerShare quickRatio  recommendationMean exchange  \
0               USD           61.241      0.893                 3.3      NYQ   
0               USD           23.601      1.185                 2.6      NYQ   
0               USD           25.139       None                 1.8      NYQ   
0               USD           32.034       None                 2.1      NYQ   
0               USD           22.703      6.133                 2.5      NMS   

                shortName                 longName exchangeTimezoneName  \
0              3M Company               3M Company     America/New_York   
0  A.O. Smith Corporation  A. O. Smith Corporation     America/New_York   
0     Abbott Laboratories      Abbott Laboratories     America/New_York   
0             AbbVie Inc.              AbbVie Inc.     America/New_York   
0           ABIOMED, Inc.            Abiomed, Inc.     America/New_York   

  exchangeTimezoneShortName  isEsgPopulated gmtOffSetMilliseconds  \
0                       EDT            True             -14400000   
0                       EDT            True             -14400000   
0                       EDT            True             -14400000   
0                       EDT            True             -14400000   
0                       EDT           False             -14400000   

  underlyingSymbol quoteType symbol underlyingExchangeSymbol headSymbol  \
0             None    EQUITY    MMM                     None       None   
0             None    EQUITY    AOS                     None       None   
0             None    EQUITY    ABT                     None       None   
0             None    EQUITY   ABBV                     None       None   
0             None    EQUITY   ABMD                     None       None   

    messageBoardId                                  uuid     market  \
0     finmb_289194  375388b3-dab7-3763-90cd-457ad19388a2  us_market   
0     finmb_997111  4cc854cc-0565-35cc-abef-bc91f30d07b0  us_market   
0     finmb_247483  5f9c82b0-139d-3f8f-b30c-efd7ee9ccdcf  us_market   
0  finmb_141885706  73238d42-cdcc-3f92-8141-dd675addae10  us_market   
0     finmb_247589  a393224e-40ae-3cd2-a2c8-12a0912a9351  us_market   

  annualHoldingsTurnover  enterpriseToRevenue beta3Year  enterpriseToEbitda  \
0                   None                2.728      None              10.191   
0                   None                2.399      None              12.362   
0                   None                4.704      None              15.514   
0                   None                5.775      None              11.513   
0                   None               11.928      None              43.268   

  52WeekChange morningStarRiskRating  forwardEps revenueQuarterlyGrowth  \
0         None                  None       10.37                   None   
0         None                  None        3.47                   None   
0         None                  None        4.76                   None   
0         None                  None       13.97                   None   
0         None                  None        5.01                   None   

   sharesOutstanding fundInceptionDate annualReportExpenseRatio totalAssets  \
0          576252992              None                     None        None   
0          133187000              None                     None        None   
0         1768290048              None                     None        None   
0         1767879936              None                     None        None   
0           45497500              None                     None        None   

   bookValue  sharesShort  sharesPercentSharesOut fundFamily  \
0     25.093      9500369                  0.0167       None   
0     11.916      4454569                  0.0286       None   
0     19.466     13461989                  0.0077       None   
0      7.665     13154753                  0.0074       None   
0     30.432      1122293                  0.0246       None   

   lastFiscalYearEnd  heldPercentInstitutions  netIncomeToCommon  trailingEps  \
0         1640908800                  0.67534         5596000256       10.111   
0         1640908800                  0.97911          509200000        2.890   
0         1640908800                  0.76305         7696000000        4.030   
0         1640908800                  0.70272        12405000192        4.196   
0         1648684800                  0.98808          136504992        3.257   

  lastDividendValue SandP52WeekChange  priceToBook  heldPercentInsiders  \
0              None              None     5.120552              0.00082   
0              None              None     4.799429              0.00719   
0              None              None     5.662180              0.00741   
0              None              None    20.065231              0.00106   
0              None              None     8.433886              0.02005   

   nextFiscalYearEnd yield  mostRecentQuarter  shortRatio  \
0         1703980800  None         1648684800        3.52   
0         1703980800  None         1648684800        3.35   
0         1703980800  None         1648684800        2.65   
0         1703980800  None         1648684800        1.52   
0         1711843200  None         1648684800        4.10   

   sharesShortPreviousMonthDate  floatShares      beta  enterpriseValue  \
0                    1648684800    568626364  0.969607      96388669440   
0                    1648684800    129763766  1.166666       8991120384   
0                    1648684800   1750132706  0.733823     209379229696   
0                    1648684800   1763801318  0.784803     327589560320   
0                    1648684800     44660516  1.325000      12307118080   

   priceHint threeYearAverageReturn lastSplitDate lastSplitFactor legalType  \
0          2                   None    1064880000             2:1      None   
0          2                   None    1475712000             2:1      None   
0          2                   None    1357084800      10000:4798      None   
0          2                   None          None            None      None   
0          2                   None     970444800             2:1      None   

  morningStarOverallRating  earningsQuarterlyGrowth  \
0                     None                   -0.200   
0                     None                    0.226   
0                     None                    0.365   
0                     None                    0.264   
0                     None                    0.061   

   priceToSalesTrailing12Months  dateShortInterest  pegRatio ytdReturn  \
0                      2.095569         1651190400      1.93      None   
0                      2.428881         1651190400      2.08      None   
0                      4.378419         1651190400      1.92      None   
0                      4.793300         1651190400      5.16      None   
0                     11.318007         1651190400     13.51      None   

   forwardPE lastCapGain  shortPercentOfFloat  sharesShortPriorMonth category  \
0  12.390551        None               0.0167                9678460     None   
0  16.481268        None               0.0391                5287955     None   
0  23.155462        None               0.0079               12103872     None   
0  11.009306        None               0.0075               13443845     None   
0  51.229538        None               0.0282                1260350     None   

  fiveYearAverageReturn  previousClose  regularMarketOpen  \
0                  None         129.41             129.41   
0                  None          54.68              55.00   
0                  None         108.65             108.21   
0                  None         153.16             153.08   
0                  None         247.51             246.42   

   twoHundredDayAverage trailingAnnualDividendYield  payoutRatio volume24Hr  \
0             161.68895                    0.045669       0.6171       None   
0              69.35795                     0.01902       0.3396       None   
0             121.92410                    0.016567       0.4223       None   
0             136.87920                    0.033951       0.7618       None   
0             307.36900                        None       0.0000       None   

   regularMarketDayHigh navPrice  averageDailyVolume10Day  \
0               129.830     None                  3438870   
0                57.455     None                  1193330   
0               110.470     None                  6229710   
0               153.860     None                  7106760   
0               256.740     None                   343420   

   regularMarketPreviousClose  fiftyDayAverage trailingAnnualDividendRate  \
0                      129.41         143.0196                       5.91   
0                       54.68          58.7068                       1.04   
0                      108.65         111.8648                        1.8   
0                      153.16         149.8344                        5.2   
0                      247.51         257.8366                       None   

     open  averageVolume10days expireDate algorithm dividendRate  \
0  129.41              3438870       None      None         5.96   
0   55.00              1193330       None      None         1.12   
0  108.21              6229710       None      None         1.88   
0  153.08              7106760       None      None         5.64   
0  246.42               343420       None      None         None   

  exDividendDate circulatingSupply startDate  regularMarketDayLow currency  \
0     1652918400              None      None             126.6100      USD   
0     1651104000              None      None              55.1700      USD   
0     1649808000              None      None             107.6500      USD   
0     1649894400              None      None             151.4590      USD   
0           None              None      None             247.3035      USD   

   trailingPE  regularMarketVolume lastMarket maxSupply openInterest  \
0   12.707942              3720829       None      None         None   
0   19.788927              1231198       None      None         None   
0   27.349874              3291666       None      None         None   
0   36.653957              4619958       None      None         None   
0   78.802580               201938       None      None         None   

      marketCap volumeAllCurrencies strikePrice  averageVolume    dayLow  \
0   74042753024                None        None        2938364  126.6100   
0    9102474240                None        None        1096637   55.1700   
0  194900934656                None        None        5486408  107.6500   
0  271899934720                None        None        7314664  151.4590   
0   11677388800                None        None         319779  247.3035   

      ask  askSize   volume  fiftyTwoWeekHigh fromCurrency  \
0  129.48      900  3720829            203.21         None   
0   71.04     1100  1231198             86.74         None   
0  109.00     1300  3291666            142.60         None   
0    0.00     1400  4619958            175.91         None   
0    0.00      800   201938            379.30         None   

  fiveYearAvgDividendYield  fiftyTwoWeekLow    bid  tradeable dividendYield  \
0                     3.05           126.61  128.1      False        0.0399   
0                     1.54            51.91    0.0      False        0.0187   
0                     1.57           101.24  108.0      False        0.0171   
0                     4.27           105.56    0.0      False        0.0367   
0                     None           219.85    0.0      False          None   

   bidSize  dayHigh  regularMarketPrice preMarketPrice  \
0      900  129.830              128.49         128.61   
0     1000   57.455               57.19           None   
0      900  110.470              110.22         108.92   
0      800  153.860              153.80         153.34   
0      800  256.740              256.66           None   

                                logo_url                 address2  \
0       https://logo.clearbit.com/3m.com                      NaN   
0  https://logo.clearbit.com/aosmith.com  Suite 170 PO Box 245008   
0   https://logo.clearbit.com/abbott.com              Abbott Park   
0   https://logo.clearbit.com/abbvie.com                      NaN   
0  https://logo.clearbit.com/abiomed.com                      NaN   

            fax  
0           NaN  
0           NaN  
0           NaN  
0           NaN  
0  978 777 8411
```

and the columns are

```
['zip',
 'sector',
 'fullTimeEmployees',
 'longBusinessSummary',
 'city',
 'phone',
 'state',
 'country',
 'companyOfficers',
 'website',
 'maxAge',
 'address1',
 'industry',
 'ebitdaMargins',
 'profitMargins',
 'grossMargins',
 'operatingCashflow',
 'revenueGrowth',
 'operatingMargins',
 'ebitda',
 'targetLowPrice',
 'recommendationKey',
 'grossProfits',
 'freeCashflow',
 'targetMedianPrice',
 'currentPrice',
 'earningsGrowth',
 'currentRatio',
 'returnOnAssets',
 'numberOfAnalystOpinions',
 'targetMeanPrice',
 'debtToEquity',
 'returnOnEquity',
 'targetHighPrice',
 'totalCash',
 'totalDebt',
 'totalRevenue',
 'totalCashPerShare',
 'financialCurrency',
 'revenuePerShare',
 'quickRatio',
 'recommendationMean',
 'exchange',
 'shortName',
 'longName',
 'exchangeTimezoneName',
 'exchangeTimezoneShortName',
 'isEsgPopulated',
 'gmtOffSetMilliseconds',
 'underlyingSymbol',
 'quoteType',
 'symbol',
 'underlyingExchangeSymbol',
 'headSymbol',
 'messageBoardId',
 'uuid',
 'market',
 'annualHoldingsTurnover',
 'enterpriseToRevenue',
 'beta3Year',
 'enterpriseToEbitda',
 '52WeekChange',
 'morningStarRiskRating',
 'forwardEps',
 'revenueQuarterlyGrowth',
 'sharesOutstanding',
 'fundInceptionDate',
 'annualReportExpenseRatio',
 'totalAssets',
 'bookValue',
 'sharesShort',
 'sharesPercentSharesOut',
 'fundFamily',
 'lastFiscalYearEnd',
 'heldPercentInstitutions',
 'netIncomeToCommon',
 'trailingEps',
 'lastDividendValue',
 'SandP52WeekChange',
 'priceToBook',
 'heldPercentInsiders',
 'nextFiscalYearEnd',
 'yield',
 'mostRecentQuarter',
 'shortRatio',
 'sharesShortPreviousMonthDate',
 'floatShares',
 'beta',
 'enterpriseValue',
 'priceHint',
 'threeYearAverageReturn',
 'lastSplitDate',
 'lastSplitFactor',
 'legalType',
 'morningStarOverallRating',
 'earningsQuarterlyGrowth',
 'priceToSalesTrailing12Months',
 'dateShortInterest',
 'pegRatio',
 'ytdReturn',
 'forwardPE',
 'lastCapGain',
 'shortPercentOfFloat',
 'sharesShortPriorMonth',
 'category',
 'fiveYearAverageReturn',
 'previousClose',
 'regularMarketOpen',
 'twoHundredDayAverage',
 'trailingAnnualDividendYield',
 'payoutRatio',
 'volume24Hr',
 'regularMarketDayHigh',
 'navPrice',
 'averageDailyVolume10Day',
 'regularMarketPreviousClose',
 'fiftyDayAverage',
 'trailingAnnualDividendRate',
 'open',
 'averageVolume10days',
 'expireDate',
 'algorithm',
 'dividendRate',
 'exDividendDate',
 'circulatingSupply',
 'startDate',
 'regularMarketDayLow',
 'currency',
 'trailingPE',
 'regularMarketVolume',
 'lastMarket',
 'maxSupply',
 'openInterest',
 'marketCap',
 'volumeAllCurrencies',
 'strikePrice',
 'averageVolume',
 'dayLow',
 'ask',
 'askSize',
 'volume',
 'fiftyTwoWeekHigh',
 'fromCurrency',
 'fiveYearAvgDividendYield',
 'fiftyTwoWeekLow',
 'bid',
 'tradeable',
 'dividendYield',
 'bidSize',
 'dayHigh',
 'regularMarketPrice',
 'preMarketPrice',
 'logo_url',
 'address2',
 'fax']
```

It doesn't matter waht you do, it will take time to retrieve that data unless you choose a reduced number of them.